# How to convert varchar yyyy-mm to date

Tags: sql, date, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, varchar

I have a column of data in the format of yyyy-mm that is VARCHAR(7). Using CONVERT doesn't work and I'm guessing it's because it needs a day in the string (yyyy-mm-dd), but I don't know how to add that to the string. I started with this code:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_X WHERE MONTH BETWEEN ('2022-06','2023-06')
```

Comment: Date and string functions are very much product-specific.

Comment: Stu, if I understand you correctly, I should have mentioned that this is in Snowflake.

Comment: What day do you want to add to the string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE_X 
WHERE MONTH BETWEEN '2022-06' AND '2023-06'
```

The comparisons between string will work, as the question states that "column of data in the format of yyyy-mm that is VARCHAR".